# Appending imported data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, import

This is what I typically use to import csv data into my postgres database..

```
\COPY master_list FROM '/root/raw/file.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Usually it's into a blank table, but in this case, I need to append the data into a table with existing data.

Will that same command suffice, or should I make changes since it's an append?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it and see.

You'll find that it works perfectly.

Now, if you want to insert data *ignoring duplicates*, that's another problem entirely.

Comment: yep, it worked fine, thanks! Out of curiosity, how would you import an append that ignore dupes?

Comment: @some1 Well-discussed topic. Search for "postgresql bulk upsert", "postgresql copy ignore duplicates", etc. You'll find a bunch of SO and DBA.SE discussions among others. Short version: `COPY` to `UNLOGGED` or `TEMPORARY` staging table then merge with SQL.